# Which privilege is required for ClickOnce to finish installation?

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, outlook, clickonce, office-interop

When I publish and install my C# app on a Windows 7 machine, I've got it installed and working beautifully. The app uses `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`.

After fixing a bug, I increased the version number and publish again. But this time, the app fails to install.

The log file seems to indicate that some privileges are missing. But I did right click the setup.exe file and run as an administrator.

What privileges are missing? How should I fix this?

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
  Windows       : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
  Common Language Runtime   : 4.0.30319.34209
  System.Deployment.dll     : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
  clr.dll       : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
  dfdll.dll       : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
  dfshim.dll      : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
  Deployment url      : file:///C:/Users/Teamroom314/Downloads/NextMeeting/NextMeeting.application
  Application url     : file:///C:/Users/Teamroom314/Downloads/NextMeeting/Application%20Files/NextMeeting_1_2_22_0/NextMeeting.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
  Deployment Identity   : NextMeeting.application, Version=1.2.22.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
  Application Identity    : NextMeeting.exe, Version=1.2.22.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
  * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
  Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
  * Activation of C:\Users\Teamroom314\Downloads\NextMeeting\NextMeeting.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service configuration and the account configuration. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070511)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
  No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
  * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
  * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:42 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\Teamroom314\Downloads\NextMeeting\NextMeeting.application has started.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:42 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:42 AM] : Installation of the application has started.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:42 AM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:43 AM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:43 AM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:43 AM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:43 AM] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:43 AM] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
  Following errors were detected during this operation.
  * [5/18/2016 11:52:50 AM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    - A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Services Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service configuration and the account configuration. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070511)
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
      at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.Transact(IntPtr cOperation, StoreTransactionOperation[] rgOperations, UInt32[] rgDispositions, Int32[] rgResults)
      at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.SubmitStoreTransaction(StoreTransactionContext storeTxn, SubscriptionState subState)
      at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
      at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
      at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
      at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
      at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
  * Transaction at [5/18/2016 11:52:50 AM]
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: G6BCL4NT.VZY.application
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
      - Status: Set
      - HRESULT: 0x0
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: NextMeeting.exe.manifest
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: chromedriver.exe
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: NextMeeting.exe.config
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: webex.ico
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: CiscoWebExv1.0.1.crx
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: WebDriver.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: WebDriver.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: ExchangeCal.exe.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: ExchangeCal.exe
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: RestSharp.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: RestSharp.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: WebExCmd.exe.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: WebExCmd.exe
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: WebDriver.Support.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: WebDriver.Support.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: CredentialManagement.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: CredentialManagement.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: NextMeeting.exe.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: NextMeeting.exe
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: Authentication.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: Authentication.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: SecVault.exe.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: SecVault.exe
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponent
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - Manifest: Library314.dll.genman
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationStageComponentFile
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - File: Library314.dll
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationInstallDeployment
      - Status: Installed
      - HRESULT: 0x0
      - AppId: file:///C:/Users/Teamroom314/Downloads/NextMeeting/NextMeeting.application#NextMeeting.application, Version=1.2.22.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
      - Status: Set
      - HRESULT: 0x0
    + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
      - HRESULT: 0x800704fb
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this problem by scanning the windows registry for the name of my application.

After deleting all entries containing my application name, I also had to delete the entries found in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\SideBySide
```

Luckily, my application is the only one using ClickOnce on this computer. Otherwise, I had to sort out which entries are mine under `SideBySide`.